# How to import to FBX in blender?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, game-development, fbx

I am totally new to blender. for my new game I downloaded http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/75021.

In blender it shows all the textures

[image]

But when I exported the model in fbx and imported it in Unity workspace BAM...No Textures

[image]

Now what is that I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the Textures that you did use into your unity project and link them back up with your materials.